# backing up rsync with hard links -- can you hard link files moved to different folders?

Tags: rsync, backup, hard-link

I use rsync for incremental backups of my folder /hi AND I use --link-dest=[some.server]/hi.  Lets say I have 1000 photos in a folder /hi/there, which is backed up on my server with rsync.

Now I move those photos from /hi/there to /hi/here.  Can I get rsync to just produce hard links for those 1000 photos, or will rsync always make new copies of those photos because they have changed (albeit only by being moved to a different folder).

It seems to me that incorporating something like fslint, we could get rsync to recognise that 1000s of files are the same, just in different directories, and make hard links instead of copies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move daily backup directories (made by rsync) to another directory in the same partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579376/move-daily-backup-directories-made-by-rsync-to-another-directory-in-the-same-p)

Comment: No. The referenced question pertains to moving directories around in the destination--i.e. in the backup. This question pertains to moving directories around in the source such that space isn't wasted in duplicates in the next backup.

Answer (score 1):

When moving a large amount of data (the saving in not storing two copies in the backup has to exceed the space in the backup used to store an extra set of metadata), what I have done a couple of times is

1. for each file in `/hi/there`, make a hardlink with the same name in `/hi/here`
2. Take a backup
3. Remove the files/hardlinks (when you make a hardlink, there's really no difference between the old and the new link to the file) in `/hi/there`

Previous backups will (of course) only contain one copy of each file, the intermediate backup will link the new names to the same copies (in the backup), and future backups will not know that the file(s) used to have other names, and will just link the new copies to the existing copies.

If you don't have space on your backup for an extra copy, there's nothing stopping you from executing step 1 and step 3 with sufficient time in between that step 2 can be a regular scheduled backup.

If you don't want your backup to contain that extra copy, that can be deleted when you have taken a new backup.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround for now. Ideally though I'd like a script to get straight to step 3.  Can we have an index for the checksum of every file, so rsync knows when it can hardlink instead of copying?

Comment: I don't think any unix filesystems will start having that, but it's more or less what backup solutions that support deduplication (I've played a little with borgbackup) does.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `--link-dest` , referencing `/hi/there`, `rsync` will create  hard links in `hi/here` to the files. You can verify this by running `ls -l` which will show you the number of hard links. If the file is unique, you will only see the number 1.
https://superuser.com/a/12975

The other way of verifying, is by looking at the unique `ionode` number of a file and comparing it between the two folders as described here:
https://superuser.com/a/12974

You could even verify this by comparing the folders, but I find comparing a single file is easier:
[How to diff two folders by inodes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57825/how-to-diff-two-folders-by-inodes)

I had the same question in relation to my incremental rsync backup and I was able to verify that the hard links are correctly being created without using additional space.

Comment: I should have specified in my original question, I'm referencing "/hi" as the --link-dest. Ideally, I would like rsync to recursively search /hi directories and make hard-links to identical files moved between /hi/there and /hi/here